# How can i automate the process of log shipping monitoring

Tags: sql-server-2005, log-shipping

I have log shipping configured between my Prod SQL server 2005 and QA SQL server 2005.        Per the requirement from Business we need to provide them with a report at the end of the day for the LOG shipping configured for multiple databases on their respective instances.

If i go manually and use standard reports, i am able to achieve this. But is there a way i can get such a report send via e-mail confirming the status of Log shipping configured amongst various DB;s in an instance.

Thanks
Kapil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script below will give you most of the information from the standard reports in SSMS when executed on your secondary server.

```
select ls.primary_server,ls.primary_database,lsd.restore_delay,
DATEDIFF(mi,lms.last_restored_date,getdate()) as time_since_last_restore,
lms.last_copied_date,lms.last_restored_date,lms.last_copied_file,
lms.last_restored_file,
lsd.disconnect_users,ls.backup_source_directory,
ls.backup_destination_directory,ls.monitor_server


from msdb.dbo.log_shipping_secondary ls
join msdb.dbo.log_shipping_secondary_databases lsd
  on lsd.secondary_id=ls.secondary_id
join msdb.dbo.log_shipping_monitor_secondary lms
  on lms.secondary_id=lsd.secondary_id
```

You can then schedule this to run daily with a SQL Agent job or if you have SSRS you can easily schedule and format the report.

If you go the SQL Agent route you will need to configure Database Mail and use that as your delivery service for the results of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Guys after lot of research and after testing on one of my servers i used the below query with slight modifications and gives perfect results, Hope this query would be useful to fetch LS status report.

```
USE [master]
GO

begin
    set nocount on
    DECLARE @Recipients varchar(275)
    DECLARE @Subject varchar(275)
    DECLARE @Body varchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @Server varchar(25)         
    DECLARE @idx int, @Status varchar(25), @DB varchar(25), @LastCopy varchar(6), @LastCFile varchar(250),
        @LastRestore varchar(6), @LastRFile varchar(250), @Latency varchar(3), @Threshold varchar(3)
    declare @retcode int
                ,@primary_id uniqueidentifier
                ,@primary_server sysname
                ,@primary_database sysname
                ,@backup_threshold int
                ,@is_backup_alert_enabled bit

                ,@secondary_id uniqueidentifier
                ,@secondary_server sysname
                ,@secondary_database sysname
                ,@restore_threshold int
                ,@is_restore_alert_enabled bit
                ,@last_copied_file nvarchar(500)
                ,@last_copied_utc datetime
                ,@time_since_last_copy int
                ,@last_restored_file nvarchar(500)
                ,@last_restored_utc datetime
                ,@time_since_last_restore int
                ,@last_restored_latency int

                ,@prev_primary_server sysname
                ,@prev_primary_database sysname

                ,@monitor_server sysname
                ,@monitor_server_security_mode int
                ,@is_monitor_local bit
                ,@curutcdate datetime
                ,@linkcmd nvarchar(4000)

SET @Recipients = 'kapil.bhasin@xyz.com'
SET @Body = ''
SET @Server = @@SERVERNAME
SET @Subject = @Server + ' :: Daily Transaction Log Shipping Status'    
SET @Body = '<p style="font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana"><b>' + @Server + ': </b></font><hr style="width: 100%; height: 1px;"> '  
    create table #log_shipping_monitor
    (
        idx int identity(1,1)
        ,status bit null
        ,is_primary bit not null default 0
        ,server sysname 
        ,database_name sysname
        ,is_backup_alert_enabled bit null
        ,time_since_last_copy int null
        ,last_copied_file nvarchar(500) null
        ,time_since_last_restore int null
        ,last_restored_file nvarchar(500) null
        ,last_restored_latency int null
        ,restore_threshold int null
        ,is_restore_alert_enabled bit null
        ,ts timestamp not null
        ,primary key (is_primary, server, database_name)
        ,unique (ts)
    )

    --
    -- create other tables we will use
    --
    create table #secondary_monitor
    (
        secondary_server sysname not null,
        secondary_database sysname not null,
        secondary_id uniqueidentifier not null,
        primary_server sysname not null,
        primary_database sysname not null,
        restore_threshold int not null, 
        threshold_alert int not null, 
        threshold_alert_enabled bit not null, 
        last_copied_file nvarchar(500) null, 
        last_copied_date datetime null, 
        last_copied_date_utc datetime null, 
        last_restored_file nvarchar(500) null, 
        last_restored_date datetime null, 
        last_restored_date_utc datetime null, 
        last_restored_latency int null, 
        history_retention_period int not null, 
        primary key (secondary_id, secondary_database)
    )

    create table #primary_monitor 
    (
        primary_id uniqueidentifier primary key not null,
        primary_server sysname not null,
        primary_database sysname not null,
        backup_threshold int not null,  
        threshold_alert int not null, 
        threshold_alert_enabled bit not null, 
        last_backup_file nvarchar(500) null, 
        last_backup_date datetime null, 
        last_backup_date_utc datetime null, 
        history_retention_period int not null,
        unique (primary_server, primary_database)
    )

    --
    -- get current time
    --
    select @curutcdate = getutcdate()
    --
    -- Enumerate the primary entries
    --
    declare #hcprimaries cursor local fast_forward for
        select 
            primary_id
            ,primary_server 
            ,primary_database 
            ,backup_threshold 
            ,threshold_alert_enabled
        from msdb.dbo.log_shipping_monitor_primary with (nolock)
        order by primary_server, primary_database

    open #hcprimaries
    fetch #hcprimaries into @primary_id, @primary_server, @primary_database, @backup_threshold, @is_backup_alert_enabled
    while (@@fetch_status != -1)
    begin
        --
        -- we have a primary entry
        --
        insert into #log_shipping_monitor (
            status
            ,is_primary
            ,server
            ,database_name
            ,is_backup_alert_enabled)
        values (
            1
            ,@primary_server
            ,@primary_database
            ,@backup_threshold
            ,@is_backup_alert_enabled)
        --
        -- process secondaries
        --
        if (upper(@primary_server) = upper(@@servername))
        begin
            --
            -- we are on primary server
            -- get monitor server information
            --
            select @monitor_server = monitor_server
                        ,@monitor_server_security_mode = monitor_server_security_mode
            from msdb.dbo.log_shipping_primary_databases
            where primary_id = @primary_id
            select @is_monitor_local = case when (upper(@monitor_server) = upper(@@servername)) then 1 else 0 end
            --
            -- enumerate the secondaries listed on primary
            --
            declare #hcprimarysecondaries cursor local fast_forward for
                select secondary_server, secondary_database
                from msdb.dbo.log_shipping_primary_secondaries with (nolock)
                where primary_id = @primary_id

            open #hcprimarysecondaries
            fetch #hcprimarysecondaries into @secondary_server, @secondary_database
            while (@@fetch_status != -1)
            begin
                --
                -- add this primary secondary to result set
                --
                insert into #log_shipping_monitor (is_primary ,server, database_name)
                    values (0, @secondary_server, @secondary_database)
                select @secondary_id = NULL
                --
                -- Enumerate this secondary from msdb.dbo.log_shipping_monitor_secondary
                --
                if (@is_monitor_local = 1)
                begin
                    --
                    -- local monitor
                    --
                    select  
                        @secondary_id = secondary_id
                        ,@restore_threshold = restore_threshold
                        ,@is_restore_alert_enabled = threshold_alert_enabled
                        ,@last_copied_file = last_copied_file
                        ,@last_copied_utc = last_copied_date_utc
                        ,@last_restored_file = last_restored_file
                        ,@last_restored_utc = last_restored_date_utc
                        ,@last_restored_latency = last_restored_latency
                    from msdb.dbo.log_shipping_monitor_secondary
                    where primary_server = upper(@primary_server)
                        and primary_database = @primary_database
                        and secondary_server = upper(@secondary_server)
                        and secondary_database = @secondary_database
                end -- local monitor
                else
                begin
                    --
                    -- remote monitor
                    --
                    if (@monitor_server_security_mode = 0) and (suser_name() != SUSER_SNAME(0x01))
                    begin
                        --
                        -- execute as proxy
                        --
                        exec @retcode = sys.sp_MSproxylogshippingmonitorhelpsecondary
                                @monitor_server = @monitor_server
                                ,@p1 = @primary_server
                                ,@p2 = @primary_database
                                ,@p3 = @secondary_server
                                ,@p4 = @secondary_database
                                ,@p5 = @secondary_id output
                                ,@p6 = @restore_threshold output
                                ,@p7 = @is_restore_alert_enabled output
                                ,@p8 = @last_copied_file output
                                ,@p9 = @last_copied_utc output
                                ,@p10 = @last_restored_file output
                                ,@p11 = @last_restored_utc output
                                ,@p12 = @last_restored_latency output                                
                    end
                    else
                    begin
                        delete #secondary_monitor
                        select @linkcmd = quotename(sys.fn_MSgetlogshippingmoniterlinkname(upper(@monitor_server))) + N'.master.sys.sp_help_log_shipping_monitor_secondary '
                                ,@retcode = 0
                        begin try
                            insert into #secondary_monitor
                            exec @retcode = @linkcmd 
                                        @secondary_server = @secondary_server
                                        ,@secondary_database = @secondary_database
                        end try
                        begin catch
                            select @retcode = 1
                                    ,@secondary_id = NULL
                        end catch

                        if (@retcode = 0)
                        begin
                            select @secondary_id = secondary_id
                                    ,@restore_threshold = restore_threshold
                                    ,@is_restore_alert_enabled = threshold_alert_enabled
                                    ,@last_copied_file = last_copied_file
                                    ,@last_copied_utc = last_copied_date_utc
                                    ,@last_restored_file = last_restored_file
                                    ,@last_restored_utc = last_restored_date_utc
                                    ,@last_restored_latency = last_restored_latency 
                            from #secondary_monitor
                            where upper(primary_server) = upper(@primary_server)
                                and primary_database = @primary_database
                        end
                        else
                        begin
                            raiserror(32031, 10, 1, @secondary_server, @secondary_database, @monitor_server)
                        end
                    end
                end -- remote monitor
                --
                -- do we have data on this secondary
                --
                if (@secondary_id is not null)
                begin
                    --
                    -- yes we do - update the entry
                    --
                    select @time_since_last_copy = datediff(minute, @last_copied_utc, @curutcdate)
                            ,@time_since_last_restore = datediff(minute, @last_restored_utc, @curutcdate)
                    update #log_shipping_monitor
                    set
                        status = case when (@time_since_last_restore > @restore_threshold or @last_restored_latency > @restore_threshold) then 1 else 0 end
                        ,time_since_last_copy = @time_since_last_copy
                        ,last_copied_file = @last_copied_file
                        ,time_since_last_restore = @time_since_last_restore
                        ,last_restored_file = @last_restored_file
                        ,last_restored_latency = @last_restored_latency
                        ,restore_threshold = @restore_threshold
                        ,is_restore_alert_enabled = @is_restore_alert_enabled
                    where upper(server) = upper(@secondary_server)
                        and database_name = @secondary_database
                end -- update secondary data
                --
                -- fetch next primary secondary
                --
                fetch #hcprimarysecondaries into @secondary_server, @secondary_database
            end
            close #hcprimarysecondaries
            deallocate #hcprimarysecondaries
        end -- we are on primary server processing primaries
        else
        begin
            --
            -- we are on monitor server
            -- get details of the secondaries from msdb.dbo.log_shipping_monitor_secondary
            -- if the same monitor is being used by secondaries
            --
            insert into #log_shipping_monitor (
                status 
                ,is_primary 
                ,server  
                ,database_name 
                ,time_since_last_copy 
                ,last_copied_file 
                ,time_since_last_restore 
                ,last_restored_file 
                ,last_restored_latency 
                ,restore_threshold 
                ,is_restore_alert_enabled)
            select 
                case when (datediff(minute, last_restored_date_utc, @curutcdate) > restore_threshold
                                        or last_restored_latency > restore_threshold) then 1 else 0 end
                ,0
                ,secondary_server
                ,secondary_database
                ,datediff(minute, last_copied_date_utc, @curutcdate)
                ,last_copied_file
                ,datediff(minute, last_restored_date_utc, @curutcdate)
                ,last_restored_file
                ,last_restored_latency
                ,restore_threshold
                ,threshold_alert_enabled
            from msdb.dbo.log_shipping_monitor_secondary (nolock)
            where primary_server = upper(@primary_server)
                and primary_database = @primary_database

        end -- we are on monitor server processing primaries
        fetch #hcprimaries into @primary_id, @primary_server, @primary_database, @backup_threshold, @is_backup_alert_enabled
    end -- while cursor for hcprimaries
    close #hcprimaries
    deallocate #hcprimaries
    --
    -- Enumerate the secondary entries
    -- minus existing secondary entries in resultset
    --
    declare #hcsecondaries cursor local fast_forward for
        select 
            secondary_server
            ,secondary_database
            ,secondary_id uniqueidentifier
            ,primary_server
            ,primary_database
            ,restore_threshold
            ,threshold_alert_enabled
            ,last_copied_file
            ,last_copied_date_utc
            ,last_restored_file
            ,last_restored_date_utc
            ,last_restored_latency
        from msdb.dbo.log_shipping_monitor_secondary with (nolock) 
        where not exists (select * from #log_shipping_monitor
                                where upper(server) = upper(secondary_server)
                                    and database_name = secondary_database
                                    and is_primary = 0)
        order by primary_server, primary_database

    open #hcsecondaries
    fetch #hcsecondaries into @secondary_server, @secondary_database, @secondary_id,
                @primary_server, @primary_database, @restore_threshold, @is_restore_alert_enabled, 
                @last_copied_file, @last_copied_utc, @last_restored_file, @last_restored_utc, @last_restored_latency
    while (@@fetch_status != -1)
    begin
        --
        -- Have we processed the primary for this secondary
        --
        if not (upper(@primary_server) = upper(@prev_primary_server)
            and @primary_database = @prev_primary_database)
        begin
            --
            -- No - Try to get the details of this primary
            --
            select @primary_id = null
            if (upper(@secondary_server) = upper(@@servername))
            begin
                --
                -- we are on secondary
                -- get monitor server information
                --
                select @monitor_server = monitor_server
                        ,@monitor_server_security_mode = monitor_server_security_mode
                from msdb.dbo.log_shipping_secondary with (nolock)
                where secondary_id = @secondary_id
                select @is_monitor_local = case when (upper(@monitor_server) = upper(@@servername)) then 1 else 0 end
                if (@is_monitor_local = 1)
                begin
                    --
                    -- local monitor
                    --
                    select @primary_id = primary_id
                        ,@backup_threshold = backup_threshold
                        ,@is_backup_alert_enabled = threshold_alert_enabled
                    from msdb.dbo.log_shipping_monitor_primary with (nolock)
                    where primary_server = upper(@primary_server)
                        and primary_database = @primary_database
                end
                else
                begin
                    --
                    -- remote monitor
                    --
                    if (@monitor_server_security_mode = 0) and (suser_name() != SUSER_SNAME(0x01))
                    begin
                        --
                        -- execute as proxy
                        --
                        exec @retcode = sys.sp_MSproxylogshippingmonitorhelpprimary
                                @monitor_server = @monitor_server
                                ,@p1 = @primary_server
                                ,@p2 = @primary_database
                                ,@p3 = @primary_id output
                                ,@p4 = @backup_threshold output
                                ,@p5 = @is_backup_alert_enabled output
                    end
                    else
                    begin
                        delete #primary_monitor
                        select @linkcmd = quotename(sys.fn_MSgetlogshippingmoniterlinkname(upper(@monitor_server))) + N'.master.sys.sp_help_log_shipping_monitor_primary '
                                ,@retcode = 0
                        begin try
                            insert into #primary_monitor
                            exec @retcode = @linkcmd 
                                        @primary_server = @primary_server
                                        ,@primary_database = @primary_database
                        end try
                        begin catch
                            select @retcode = 1
                                    ,@primary_id = NULL
                        end catch

                        if (@retcode = 0)
                        begin
                            select @primary_id = primary_id
                                    ,@backup_threshold = backup_threshold
                                    ,@is_backup_alert_enabled = threshold_alert_enabled
                            from #primary_monitor
                        end
                        else
                        begin
                            raiserror(32030, 10, 1, @primary_server, @primary_database, @monitor_server)
                        end
                    end -- processing remote
                end
            end -- processing on secondary
            else
            begin
                --
                -- we are on monitor server
                --
                select @primary_id = primary_id
                    ,@backup_threshold = backup_threshold
                    ,@is_backup_alert_enabled = threshold_alert_enabled
                from msdb.dbo.log_shipping_monitor_primary with (nolock)
                where primary_server = upper(@primary_server)
                    and primary_database = @primary_database
            end -- processing on monitor server
            --
            -- insert primary details if available
            --
            if (@primary_id is not null)
            begin
                select @prev_primary_server = @primary_server
                        ,@prev_primary_database = @primary_database
                insert into #log_shipping_monitor (
                    status
                    ,is_primary
                    ,server
                    ,database_name
                    ,is_backup_alert_enabled)
                values (
                1
                    ,@primary_server
                    ,@primary_database
                    ,@backup_threshold
                    ,@is_backup_alert_enabled)
            end -- primary data available
        end -- process the primary
        --
        -- Insert the secondary
        --
        select @time_since_last_copy = datediff(minute, @last_copied_utc, @curutcdate)
                ,@time_since_last_restore = datediff(minute, @last_restored_utc, @curutcdate)
        insert into #log_shipping_monitor (
            status 
            ,is_primary 
            ,server  
            ,database_name 
            ,time_since_last_copy 
            ,last_copied_file 
            ,time_since_last_restore 
            ,last_restored_file 
            ,last_restored_latency 
            ,restore_threshold 
            ,is_restore_alert_enabled)
        values (
            case when (@time_since_last_restore > @restore_threshold or @last_restored_latency > @restore_threshold) then 1 else 0 end
            ,0
            ,@secondary_server
            ,@secondary_database
            ,@time_since_last_copy
            ,@last_copied_file
            ,@time_since_last_restore
            ,@last_restored_file
            ,@last_restored_latency
            ,@restore_threshold
            ,@is_restore_alert_enabled)
        --
        -- get the next secondary
        --
        fetch #hcsecondaries into @secondary_server, @secondary_database, @secondary_id,
                    @primary_server, @primary_database, @restore_threshold, @is_restore_alert_enabled, 
                    @last_copied_file, @last_copied_utc, @last_restored_file, @last_restored_utc, @last_restored_latency
    end -- while cursor for hcsecondaries
    close #hcsecondaries
    deallocate #hcsecondaries
    --
    -- return resultset
    --
SET @Body = RTRIM(@Body) + '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">'

    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 idx FROM #log_shipping_monitor)
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @idx = idx, @Status = (CASE WHEN status  = 0 THEN 'Good' ELSE 'Bad' END),
            @DB = database_name, @LastCopy = time_since_last_copy, @LastCFile =  last_copied_file,
            @LastRestore = time_since_last_restore, @LastRFile = last_restored_file,
            @Latency = last_restored_latency, @Threshold = restore_threshold 
        FROM #log_shipping_monitor      order by ts

        SET @Body = RTRIM(@Body) 
        + '<tr><td nowrap style="font-size:11px;font-family:Verdana">'
            + '<b>Database</b>:' + RTRIM(@DB) + '
'
            + CASE WHEN @Status = 'Good' THEN
                '<b>Status</b>:' + RTRIM(@Status) + '
'
                ELSE '<b>Status</b>:<font size="+1" color="red">' + RTRIM(@Status) + '</font>
' END           
            + '<b>Last Copied File</b>:' + RTRIM(@LastCFile) + '
'
            + '<b>Time since last Copy (min)</b>:' + RTRIM(@LastCopy) + '
'
            + '<b>Last Restored File</b>:' + RTRIM(@LastRFile) + '
'
            + '<b>Time since last Restore (min)</b>:' + RTRIM(@LastRestore) + '
'
            + '<b>Restore Latency (min)</b>:' + RTRIM(@Latency) + '
'
            + '<b>Restore Threshold (min)</b>:' + RTRIM(@Threshold) + '
'
            + '</td></tr>'
            + '<hr style="width: 100%; height: 1px;"> ' 
        DELETE FROM #log_shipping_monitor WHERE idx = @idx
    END

SET @Body = RTRIM(@Body) + '</table>'
        EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients = @Recipients 
                ,@subject = @Subject
                ,@profile_name = 'XYZ'
                ,@body = @Body
                ,@body_format = 'HTML'



end

DROP Table #log_shipping_monitor
DROP TABLE #primary_monitor
DROP TABLE #secondary_monitor
```

Comment: Thanks John for editing. I tried but was not able to do so. Can you let me know how does that work?